# with, if together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use `if` statement to validate `with` statement together.

example:

```py
if with statement as t:
   t.insert(condition)
   print("notification processed successfully")
else:
   print("notification not processed successfully")
```

I am new to python so not have much idea. Any help will be great.

Please find attachment for the same.

[image]

Comment: What condition should the `if` be testing? It is not obvious where there is a boolean value to test.

Comment: you can't mix it in that way. You start a loop with the "with" statment and that put the if clause within

Comment: You can enclose that in a try-except block and upon catching the exception in the except block, return False or set a check so you can do what ever that needs to be done. (I assumed your trans.insdert does not return any thing and on failure just and exception occurs)

Comment: @Rika , In case of success it returns "Notification successfully processed" but in case of failure it returns "500" error. So, i just wanted that in case of failure it should also return "Notification not processed successfully". So trying to change a code but here but was confused here "with" statement here.

Comment: @daminichopra : please add the implementation details of `trans.insert()` to your question. that way we can easily tell you what to do. right now we have no Idea what insert returns, if it returns anything at all! so that makes it different. if it returns sth, you can use if statement after your call to insert and based on what you recieved, display the needed text. if it returns nothing, then it should be know what behavior it shows (does it raise an exception or it simply returns without any errors , etc)

Comment: @daminichopra please accept my answer if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: @Rika," ```trans.insert```" has "```payload, fiware_s, fiware_sp```" these values and "```payload```" has json entry "```{'id': 'Room2', 'happiness': {'value': 'Null', 'type': 'Text'}, 'type': 'Room7', 'time_index': '2020-07-29T04:31:04.297783'}```" .. if ```trans.insert``` able to insert payload to database then it will show message ```"Notification processed successfully"``` otherwise if not able to store data in database ```"Notification not processed successfully"````... so just wanted to add exception for not processed notification in this code block.  Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/smartsdk/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/e780a30c8cb8f7b920f449b60512e1daef6d9b41/src/translators/factory.py#L34

Comment: if all you need is a try except block then sth like this should do it!:
```try:
    with translate_for() as trans: 
     trans.insert(...)
  print('ok')
except Exception as exp: 
 print(f'not successful!! exception msg: {exp.args}')``` I really dont quite understand you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` within the `with` statement

```
with statement as t:
     if condition:

     else:
```

edit: where `condition` is what you want the `if` statement to check

Comment: ```If trans.insert(condition)==1 
 print "success"
else: 
print "not success"```
something like this can be used???